# Execute SQL arithmetic stored as string (stored procedure? c#?)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to figure out the best way of doing this....SQL SERVER stored procedure? also contemplating doing it in c#, but either way I'm sortof at a stand still.

Basically what I have is a parts table and a column with qty. This qty column could be a fixed number but it could also be dependent on other parameters. (length, width, size etc...). This was originally a very basic project and I cheated with a few if statements, however an increasing number of parts have a calculated quantity. I want to be able to execute a function stored as a string when a certain part should be selected.

so then based on the parts needed, a table would be created with part and its corresponding numeric quantity.

I was reading into sp_executesql, EXEC, but they still aren't making sense (havent found an comparable example)

Table:

```
PART   QTY
==========
 X    'CASE WHEN @FinWidth >=124 THEN ROUND(1.5 + (@FinHeight-@FinWidth)/2.2,0) ELSE 10 END'    
 Y    '2'
```

Query:

```
    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @qty decimal(18,3)
    DECLARE @finHeight decimal(18,3)
    DECLARE @finWidth decimal(18,3)
    DECLARE @part varchar(80)


    SET @finHeight = 120
    SET @finWidth = 100


    sp_executesql....something??
    EXEC(something)??
```

Comment: I see no reason why you would want dynamic SQl, but since the sql statement you built has a syntax error (no from clause) it would never run.  But to really help you we need to see the sample data that illustrrates the problem and the sample results.

Comment: Well I assumed dynamic would be the only way to go considering I have a different function in each record of the table that needs to be executed with/without parameters. I'm open to any other suggestions. (that select statement was just an example of table output) I don't have any output because clearly this wouldn't work as is lol

Comment: You are storing the formula in the qty field? Really? Well personally rather than mess with this I would redesign your table so that Qty is always a number. This schema will never work well in the long run and as you get more records it will get harder and hared to get good data out. This is a problem so bad that that database needs refactoring before you get any more records in there.

Comment: Qty is an undefined number until there are input parameters. I'm storing the code to generate that quantity for each part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can get you to use string from table and calculate it. Since it's dynamic SQL you can't use it as function, so I am not sure how useful it can be... you can maybe try with stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @finHeight decimal(18,3)
DECLARE @finWidth decimal(18,3)
DECLARE @part varchar(80)

SET @part = 'X'

SET @finHeight = 124
SET @finWidth = 400
SELECT @sqlCommand= 'SELECT ' + QTY FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE PART = @part

SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '@finHeight', @finHeight)
SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '@finWidth', @finWidth)

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3a3e/2)**

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function to return quantity based on the business logic related to misc fields. Example function would be

```
create dbo.fn_GetQuantity(@Qty int, @width decimal(18, 3), @Height decimal(18,3))
returns int
as
begin
    -- TODO Apply all business logic related to @width & @height here and calculate new @Qty
    return @Qty
end
```

then in the proc I would just call this new function with needed parameters.

```
create proc dbo.sGetParts()
as
begin
    select Part, dbo.fn_GetQuantity(Qty, finWidth, finWidth)
    from parts
end
```

Comment: Hmm okay multiple functions seems like a good idea, I just dont know how to grab the string stored for qty and execute it and return me a decimal

Comment: Just one function, no need for multiple functions. You are saying that qty in parts table will actually have the expression for qty as string and you want evaluate it?

Comment: Yea, this is a parts configurator where certain parts get selected based on answers to questions and I figured this would be the easiest way to program this. Before, when I only had a few calculated quantities, I did an If based on partnumber and then had the necessary function there. (that was messy and not expandable)

Comment: I wont recommend going down the path of storing expressions in column, down the road it will be really hard to manage it.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I'm still a noobie when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: How are the values for Height, Width & Size available for a part? is it all stored as columns in Parts table or user will input it at runtime?

Comment: Users answer questions based on options. These options lead to parts being added to a Bill of Materials. They also enter height/width.